# Counter example for function problem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

if $X$ is a finite set with $f: X\to X$ and $g: X\to X$, then $f \circ g = 1_X$ if and only if $g \circ f = 1_X$. Give a counter example to show that this is not true for infinite sets.

Had a small idea of the function $f: X \to X$ given by $f(x) = 2x$ is injective, and so has a left inverse $g: X \to X$
But wasn't sure where to take this

Comment: Your idea is almost there. What were you thinking the set $X$ is? What is the left inverse $g$? Is $f\circ g=1_X$? Is $g\circ f=1_X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good choice for $f$. But what is $X$?

Let's take $X$ to be the positive integers. What is the $g$ so that $g \circ f=I_X$? Of course $g(x) =\frac{x}{2}$ if $x$ is even.

What is $g(x)$ when $x$ is odd? Doesn't matter, odd positive integers are not in the range of $f$. So take $g(x )= 1$ for all odd positive integers, just so that $g$ is not injective, thus $f\circ g \ne 1_X$. For instance, for all odd $x$, $(f \circ g) (x) =f(1)=2 $.

Comment: you said odd positive integers are not in the range of f but then u said take g(x) for all positive integers ?